# Mean of diffusion term not zero using NORMINV?

Tags: returns, brownian-motion, geometric-brownian

maybe this is a question considered too basic for all of you but im new so please excuse:
I wanted to buid a simulation in excel using the usual suspect(STANDNORMINV(RAND()) and i tried to calculate the mean for an arithmetic and geometricx brownian motion. However, i noted that this doesn't seem to work. I separated drift and diffision for my ABM and while my mean of the drift for ABM is  as i expected (mu*T), the mean of my diffusion term is nowhere near zero. I attached a pic plus the formulas i used. Please don't close this quesion prematurely (or do it but leave a comment what i am doing wrong plz.)[image]

[image]

Comment: If I call in excel the function `NORMINV(RAND(),0,1)` five thousand times I get a mean of `-0.02861` . That this is not exactly zero I attribute to Monte Carlo noise.

Comment: @BussiHasi Welcome! I tried to figure out where your confusion comes from, adding your pics somewhat helped but im not sure the excel is cleaned up as the mean-function points to another cell..

Please correct me if i'm wrong but you try to calculate the mean from an arithmetic brownian motion, not just of `NORMINV(RAND(),0,1)`, correct? So your question is about whether the process modeled is correct?

Comment: Yes , im confused about the WURZEL() in the ABM, it seems this destroys my mean as it scales my small difference too much.. dunno whether its correct in my column and how i need to scale my mean to get a annual mean from my daily returns.. i know.. newbie questions